# PowerShell Socket Programming

Tags: powershell

I've been struggling some with building a non-blocking TCP server in Powershell. This is purely something I am doing from a personal understanding nature and was wondering what I might be missing.

When I create a socket:

```
$IPEndPoint = New-Object SystemNet.IPEndpoint($Global:ServerAddress, $Global:ServerPort)
$SocketType = [System.Net.Sockets.SocketType]::Stream
$ProcotocolType = [System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType]::Tcp
$Listener = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.Socket($IPEndPoint.Address.AddressFamily,
                $SocketType,$ProcotocolType)
```

I don't seem to grok how to handle BeginAccept with it; what my goal here is to be able to grab the incoming socket connection handing it off on event and continue processing connections. The handed-off socket connection will be passed to a communications object that will work with it. This is fairly trivial in most languages, and I believe I've missed the wagon.

I've been testing various methods of Register-EventObject and also even attempted with a System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.

While I can receive multiple requests, I'm having an issue working these requests separately and handing off the incoming socket or client object. What is the best/preferred way to do this?

Comment: I got a slack bot working in PowerShell using web sockets, see if this helps at all: http://wragg.io/powershell-slack-bot-using-the-real-time-messaging-api/

Comment: Thanks Mark, I've gotten so far as being able to handle a single-thread communication pretty well. It's interesting to see how you've done it as well, but I was really looking at how to handle the non-blocking connection and hand-off to the callback read/write methods. This is for an interactive telnet server, the only thing remotely similar I've seen have used timer events which seems really odd for Powershell.

Comment: Honestly I'd use C# for something like this, however if you want to use BeginAccept and the other async methods, you need to use a way to implement asynchronous notifications, here is an example: http://www.nivot.org/post/2009/10/09/PowerShell20AsynchronousCallbacksFromNET

Comment: @MickyBalladelli thanks for Callback Bridge note, I had looked at this before, but since it was PS2.0 I was hoping for a better way. It seems that there is no way around using Add-Type and C# for callbacks.

Comment: @PetSerAl Yes, this is more or less what I was looking for, I've tweaked it a bit and having issues with multiple connections, but considering you handled the Async call and the pass-off, that is dead on.